# mocha testing doesn't work in the yeoman ember generator

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, yeoman

I've barely modify the generated code by the ember generator

`yo ember`

and change the test/spec/test.js a little bit

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    describe('Give it some context', function () {
        describe('maybe a bit more context here', function () {
            it('should equal to the title', function () {
                var title = document.title;
                title.should.equal('Ember Starter Kit');
                            console.log(title) //doesn't output anything in the terminal
            });
            it('should equal to a number', function () {
                1.should.equal(1);
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

There's two strange thing:

1. console.log doesn't output anything in the terminal
2. it shows 0 test:

   Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
   Testing: http://*.*.*.*/index.html

   0 tests complete (1 ms)

   Done, without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that when you get a "0 tests complete", there's an error within the test file.

There are two problems with your test:

1. Missing semicolon after console.log(title)
2. Executing a method on an Integer is a syntax error. Try the following:

`expect(1).to.equal(1);`

Also, be sure to include the following lines in your `index.html` after the Chai inclusion (so that `should` works):

```
...
<!-- assertion framework -->
<script src="lib/chai.js"></script>
<script>var expect = chai.expect</script>
<script>var should = chai.should()</script>
...
```

This causes your tests to run. However, I don't have an answer to the console logging problem. I'm looking for an answer myself. Seems to be something with grunt-mocha and PhantomJS.

**Edit:** Turns out, the console logging in grunt-mocha is disabled: [grunt-mocha source](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/blob/master/tasks/mocha.js#L100-L101).

If you go into your `node_modules/grunt-mocha/tasks/mocha.js` within the project directory, you can uncomment line 101, and logging will work for your project.

Full updated test file:

```
/*global describe, it, document, expect */
'use strict';
(function () {
    describe('Give it some context', function () {
        describe('maybe a bit more context here', function () {
            it('should equal to the title', function () {
                var title = document.title;
                title.should.equal('Ember Starter Kit');
                            console.log(title); //doesn't output anything in the terminal
            });
            it('should equal to a number', function () {
                expect(1).to.equal(1);
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

**Edit:** From the developer of grunt-mocha:

*Yup, uncomment that line to get console output in the command line... although generally you don't want that when you are running automated tests so it's disabled by default. If you want to really debug, I would suggest opening the spec in a browser and using the browser console/debugger. Bonus is that you can click on the suite/test so that it only runs the tests you are interested in.*

Comment: Hi Dan. Your answer really works for me, But could you explain, what's the point if mocha testing a empty `index.html(/test/index.html)`, instead of the real ember app? because `console.log(document.title)` output 'Mocha  test runner', not real ember app

Comment: Tests are meant to run in an environment complete with fixtures to test the functionality of whatever pieces you're working with. So, if the portion of your application makes a change to the title, you can test that. The `index.html` file is a test-runner meant to allow whatever DOM changes are needed from your app.